# How to update a list item from web service using a where clause?

Tags: list, web-services, caml-query

I have a scenario where I need to update a list item, but I don't know the internal ID of the list item - hence the following won't work for me:

```
batchElement.InnerXml = "<Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'>" +
            "<Field Name='ID'>" + id + "</Field>" + 
            "<Field Name='DeliveryStatus'>" + newStatus.ToString() + "</Field></Method>";
```

Instead I have another field in the list called ProcessID:

So I would like to update the delivery status where ProcessID = X

Is this possible using SharePoint web services.

One solution I was thinking of is to first do a select for the ID based on the ProcessID - then update based on this ID, but this seems like a crazy solution, surely the inventors of MOSS CAML would have provided a way to update a list item by some means of a where clause, or using another field for filtration rather than just plain old ID?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you're crazy solution is the right one - select for the items to get the IDs, then update.

It's not much different to uploading a document - that can involve an HTTP PUT, setting the metadata, and then checking the item in - that's 3 HTTP requests for what I though should be 1...

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing a few nodes.  You should need the following:

```
<updates><Batch OnError='Continue'>{CAML}</Batch></updates>
```

Comment: @Mike - thanks my batch element contains this, but I am in search of a way to update a list item based on a field other than id, any idea how this is done?